# is there a way of adding a folder on my branch to specifically commit it to a new repo on github?

Tags: git, github, git-bash

i created a new branch (firstbranch) different from my main / master branch on git and i want to add a specific folder to that branch, commit and push it to my new repo created on github. but each time i try to add all the files in that folder using `git add .` and run git status i get this:

```
$ git status
On branch firstbranch
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

is there something am missing out? because i had already successfully pushed files via my main branch to my repo on github. i want this to go via my branch to my github repo so i can make some modifications to it and when am done i will then post it to my main branch.

Comment: Is there anything in the folder?

Comment: is the folder excluded in your .gitignore? Is the folder being added to the correct directory?

Comment: git works with file no directory, add a dummy file like `.donotdelete` to commit it

Comment: @Mureinik, there are files in that folder

Comment: @Jake, the folder is added to my repo directory which has other folders in it too asides the one i want to push. inside the repo directory i have 4 different folders

Comment: @Ôrel, yes i even entered the directory i want to push and selected a file inside, main.py and tried adding it to the staging area but when i run git status i still get the initial nothing to commit message

Comment: Sounds like ignored stuff. Run `git status --ignored`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what do you get when you do `git add <file>` ?